# Search form errors

Tags: php

Good day eveyone!

I am trying to make a simple search engine. In my db, I have placed a column for keywords(key) so that whenever I try to search something that has the same word on the keywords, it would show its result. But why isn't the code working. It doesn't return any result and it also have an error:

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

I need your help.

**search.php**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action='search.php' method='get'>
        <input type='text' name='k' size='50' value='<?php echo $_GET['k']; ?>' />
        <input type='submit' value='search'>    
    </form>

<?php
    $k = $_GET['k'];
    $terms = explode(" ", $k);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM book_info WHERE ";
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($terms as $each)
    {
        $i++;
        if($i == 1)
            $q .= "key LIKE '%$each%'";
        else 
            $q .= "OR key LIKE '%$each%'";
    }

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("library_books");

    $q = mysql_query($q);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($q);

    if($numrows >0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
            $title = $row['title'];
            $author= $row['author'];
            $isbn= $row['isbn'];

        echo "$title<br /> $author<br />$isbn <br />";

        }

    }else
        echo "No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";
    mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action='search.php' method='get'>
        <input type='text' name='k' size='50' />
        <input type='submit' value='search'>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $q .= "OR key LIKE '%$each%'"; give a space as $q .= " OR key LIKE '%$each%'";

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, Seems like he left a space already after the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: yes but in the else condition I guess it needs some space since for multiple words it will create the issue !!

Comment: change variable name like this:   $result = mysql_query($q);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result );

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thanks for the help sir. I did what you told but still not working.

Comment: use mysql_error() to see if something obvious !!

Comment: @AbhishekSaha I am still receiving the mysql_num_rows error.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha it says that "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key LIKE '%the%' OR key LIKE '%girl%'' at line 1" Is this something to do with my query?

Comment: Before using mysql_query, try to print the sql. echo $q; also check if your database has those columns and have no typos

Comment: I guess there ain't no typo
SELECT * FROM book_info WHERE key LIKE '%the%' OR key LIKE '%girl%' The name for my keyword container from db is key

Comment: Ah u are using reserved word key in the query back tick them as ` `key` `

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thanks for the tip sir. Now the mysql_num_rows error has faded away! One error left, it won't show any results

Comment: so may be the query is returning 0 rows ? echo the query and use the same in mysql directly and see if its returning anything.

Comment: whenever i echo the $q it would give me Resource id #4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreach loop has a error. If you have multiple rows, your sql will start like "WHERE OR..", which shouldnt be the case. Replce with the below code.

```
$mutiple = false;
foreach ($terms as $each)
{
    $i++;
    if(sizeof($terms) == 1) {
        $q .= "`key` LIKE '%$each%'";
    }
    else {  
        if($multiple) $q .= " OR ";
        $q .= "`key` LIKE '%$each%'";
        $mutiple = true;
    }
}
```

Also change

```
 $terms = explode(" ", $k);
```

to

```
$terms = array_map('trim', explode(' ', $k));
```

Comment: Still the same result. i don't seem to get what is wrong the my code.

Comment: can you echo $q and print it here.

Comment: SELECT * FROM book_info WHERE ' key ' LIKE '%The%' ' key ' LIKE '%girl%' OR ' key ' LIKE '%%' <--- this seems to have an extra %%.

Comment: i have change the if condition.

Comment: change the if condition. it has to work. refer my code.

Comment: Thank you for your utmost generosity of helping me sir but sad to say, It doesn't work either. Whenever I echo the $q, it still gives me the query with an extra %% .

Comment: No problem. I have added a change. Could you please try that.

Comment: Now it's working! Thanks. One question umm.. if example, i'll not be using any keyword for it but instead i'll let the user search by it's title, or author or its isbn. How can i do that?

Comment: check if title is null or not. if not add the where clause. But remember to use OR properly. You try from your own first. If you are not able to, paste some code. We will help you fix that.

Comment: where should i place the if statement? can i place it inside the if(sizeof($terms) == 1) statement??

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
    $k = isset($_GET['k']) ? $_GET['k'] : 'no result';
    $terms = explode(" ", $k);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM book_info WHERE ";
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($terms as $each)
    {
        $i++;
        if($i == 1)
            $q .= "book_info.key LIKE '%$each%'";
        else 
            $q .= " OR book_info.key LIKE '%$each%'";
    }



    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("library_books", $link);

    $result = mysql_query($q, $link);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($numrows >0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $title = $row['title'];
            $author= $row['author'];
            $isbn= $row['isbn'];

        echo "$title<br /> $author<br />$isbn <br />";

        }

    }else
        echo "No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";
    mysql_close();
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action='search.php' method='get'>
        <input type='text' name='k' size='50' value='<?php echo $k; ?>' />
        <input type='submit' value='search'>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help sir but it is still not working.

Comment: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

`$q = mysql_query($q);
alert($q);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($q);`

Check if your database actually returns something.

Comment: I mean, insert the line <code>alert($q);</code> into your code. You did that right?

Comment: Yes. It gave me a fatal error sir. Unidentified function alert

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken with other languages. It's 'echo $q;' that you should try.

Comment: It doesn't give error but instead, it gave me this  Resource id #4

Comment: Weird. That should be a valid variable for the mysql_num_rows function. Normally I use a mysql_fetch_array after mysql_query, but that is optional as far as I know. If that doesn't work, I can't help you.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help sir. Really appreciate it.